# fill a dictionary from rows in a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I would like to populate a multitude of dictionaries with values contained in a dataframe. Ideally, each row should be used to fill one dictionary, which will be appended to a list of dictionaries.

```
#example df
firstname | lastname | dob        | modified   | created
john        smith      1990-01-01   2019-10-11   2015-06-25
becca       meyers     1995-04-13   2020-01-08   2018-05-18
```

each dictionary should look like this: (please ignore the fact this makes no sense given the example, it's just how it has to be done)

```
d = {
  "firstname" : {
      "value": df['firstname'],
      "modified": df['modified'],
      "created": df['created']
   },{
   "lastname": {
     "value": df['lastname'],
     "modified": df['modified'],
     "created": df['created']
   }
}
```

I have tried doing a `for` loop through the df, but it just populated the whole dataframe in each field, which is not what I was hoping for.

```
l = []
for x in df:
    d = {
        "firstname" : {
            "value": df['firstname'],
            "modified": df['modified'],
            "created": df['created']
        },{
        "lastname": {
            "value": df['lastname'],
            "modified": df['modified'],
            "created": df['created']
           }
       }
    l.append(d)
```

ninjaedit: my anticipated output should be:

```
l = [{ 
   "firstname": {
   "value": "john",
   "modified": 2019-10-11,
   "created": 2015-06-25}
   },{
   "lastname": {
   "value": "smith",
   "modified": 2019-10-11,
   "created": 2015-06-25}},
   ...
}]
```

It's been a couple of months since I've done anything `python`/`pandas` so I'm a bit out of practice. Thanks in advance. Sorry if this is confusing, I can expand if need be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.itertuples`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.itertuples.html):

```
l = []
for x in df.itertuples():
    d = {
        "firstname" : {
            "value": x.firstname,
            "modified": x.modified,
            "created": x.created
        },
        "lastname": {
            "value": x.lastname,
            "modified": x.modified,
            "created": x.created
            }
        }
    l.append(d)
print (l)

[{'firstname': {'value': 'john', 'modified': '2019-10-11', 'created': '2015-06-25'}, 
  'lastname': {'value': 'smith', 'modified': '2019-10-11', 'created': '2015-06-25'}}, 
 {'firstname': {'value': 'becca', 'modified': '2020-01-08', 'created': '2018-05-18'}, 
  'lastname': {'value': 'meyers', 'modified': '2020-01-08', 'created': '2018-05-18'}}]
```

Slowier alternative:

```
l = []
for i, x in df.iterrows():
    d = {
        "firstname" : {
            "value": x.firstname,
            "modified": x.modified,
            "created": x.created
        },
        "lastname": {
            "value": x.lastname,
            "modified": x.modified,
            "created": x.created
            }
        }
    l.append(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use df.iterrows() in loop

Here little article about this [how iterate pandas dataframe](https://cmdlinetips.com/2018/12/how-to-loop-through-pandas-rows-or-how-to-iterate-over-pandas-rows/)

Comment: Cheers! I'll read into it. Unfortunately, anytime one googles `dict` and `dataframe` in the same query, I get results for constructing dataframes from dictionaires.

Comment: it happens, but it will be great if you try to understand  how your script should work and  then try google specific algorithm . Like, I want add values from my dataframe line by line to list. Then you search  how iterate dataframe :)